# Best algorithm or procedure to perform video fingerprinting

Tags: python, video, video-streaming, video-processing, fingerprinting

I was going through the documentation of video fingerprinting and as per what I have understood its mostly image processing. First, step is to break the video into multiple images for each unit of time and than any one of pHash, dHash, wHash or average Hash can be calculated and compared for video fingerprinting.

But, the issue is comparing hash from hashes of all videos stored in database is time taking job and in case of live streaming delay of more than 2 seconds is a problem. So, is there any other process or algorithm to perform video fingerprinting or is there is any way in which hashes comparison can be performed fast

Comment: How is it that you already have a database of videos that can be checked against some future (or "not yet happened") live events? Doesn't make sense...

Comment: PS: Things that might help with speed improvements... **(1)** Use GPU for your math calculations (don't know if it's possible, I'm not a Python user). **(2)** Keep Array of each "first pixel color" (from first non-black frame) as extracted from each database videos, then look for such color in the first pixel of livestream frames (when found, you check if rest of DB frame's pixels match with those from the live frame). **(3)** Try **frame differencing** to know if there is a big change in live picture (maybe it cut to your database video). You can scale image size down for faster assesment.